# Latex subfigure put index inside the figure with picture environment

Tags: subfloats

**What I want to achieve**:
I want to place several figure side by side and I want to place the figure index inside the figure at the top left corner.

**What I have done so far**:
The first part i.e. images can be placed side by side in a grid easily by using `subfig`. But using only `subfig` the image index can't be put inside the figure. For that purpose, I am using the latex `picutre` environment and have come up with this

```latex
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}
\textheight 9.0in
\textwidth 6.8in
\topmargin -0.7cm
\oddsidemargin -0.5cm
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{color} 


\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright,farskip=12pt,captionskip=12pt,position=auto,labelfont=bf,labelformat=empty}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue}


\newcommand{\len}{}

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.2\textheight}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\subfloat[Sample fig 1 \label{mysubfig1}]{
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
        \put(0,0){\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-a}}
        \put(0,0.9){(a)}
    \end{picture}
}
    
\subfloat[Sample fig 2 \label{mysubfig2}]{
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
        \put(0,0){\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-b}}
        \put(0,0.9){(b)}
    \end{picture}
}\\
    
        \caption{A sample image grid with \ref{mysubfig1}, \ref{mysubfig2}. }
        \label{fulfig1}
\end{figure}
    
        
    
\end{document}
```

**Problem**
The figure does not get placed side by side, they appear as one bottom to another. Also the sizes are not very portable either, I have to set them by trial and error.

Is there any way to put the figure side by side nicely and also place the image index to the top left corner of the figure inside the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- That images be side-by-sude, remove empty lines between `subfloat`s.
- But doing this, you will still have sub caption text below. Is this desired? Or you like remove this text?
- Images overlap because they are to wide. Limit their width by `\includegraphics` option ˛width=...`. For example with` width=0.4\textwidth`.
- It is not clear, does images should be separated for some amount of space or should touch each other.

One way, how can you managed your problem is by use of `tikz` package and a bit longer code the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}

    \tikzset{inner sep=0pt}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
\subfloat[\label{mysubfig1}]{%
\tikz{\node (a) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
      \node[below right=2mm] at (a.north west) {(a) Sample fig. 1};  
%     \node[below right=2mm] at (a.north west) {(a)}; % when you not liked to have text in image caption
      }}
\hfil
\subfloat[\label{mysubfig2}]{%
\tikz{\node (a) {\includegraphics{example-image-b}};
      \node[below right=2mm] at (a.north west) {(b) Sample fig. 2};
      }}

\caption{A sample image grid with subimages \subref{mysubfig1} and \subref{mysubfig2}. }
\label{fulfig1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: In the case, that image should touch each other, remove `\hfil` between `subfloat`s

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the `tikz` package. It exactly does what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I change my answer.

Like this:

[image]

with this code (in fact Your code with little changes):

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}
\textheight 9.0in
\textwidth 6.8in
\topmargin -0.7cm
\oddsidemargin -0.5cm
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{color} 


\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright,farskip=12pt,captionskip=12pt,position=auto,labelfont=bf,labelformat=empty}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue}


\newcommand{\len}{}

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.2\textheight}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        
        \subfloat[\label{mysubfig1}]{
            \begin{picture}(1,1)
                \put(0,0){\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-a}}
                \put(0,0.9){(a) Sample fig. 1}
            \end{picture}
        }
        \qquad \qquad
        \subfloat[\label{mysubfig2}]{
            \begin{picture}(1,1)
                \put(0,0){\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-b}}
                \put(0,0.9){(b) Sample fig. 2}
            \end{picture}
        }\\
        \vspace{-1cm}
        \caption{A sample image grid with \ref{mysubfig1}, \ref{mysubfig2}. }
        \label{fulfig1}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @Eular, it solve. See edited version (+1 for it).